# entity framework nested conditions

Tags: linq, entity-framework

Hi i have a model where i have to count the rows with conditions:
uscitaservizio == false and accountid attribute (int) is in a string filtrodipe

es: filtrodipe = "2,4,5,6"

I' ve tried with this:

```
db.TDP_Missioni.Count( p => p.UscitaServizio == false && 
                    (objUser.FiltroDipe != null ? (p.AccountID.ToString() in objUser.FiltroDipe.Split(',')) : true))
```

But it's incorrect.

How can i do?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

In a case like this I would normally pull apart my query logic to keep it easier to read (leave the in-line conditional out of the query itself). To simplify my sample I'm not safely parsing the accountIds, though I'd recommend doing so in your final code (use `int.TryParse()` instead).

```
var missions = db.TDP_Missioni.Where(p => !p.UscitaServizio);

if (objUser.FiltroDipe != null)
{
    var accountIds = objUser.FiltroDipe.Split(',').Select(a => int.Parse(a));
    missions = missions.Where(m => accountIds.Contains(m.AccountID));
}

var missionCount = missions.Count();
```

If you prefer to keep this all in a single query, the key portion to look at is `accountIds.Contains(m.AccountID)`.
Changing `(p.AccountID.ToString() in objUser.FiltroDipe.Split(','))` to `objUser.FiltroDipe.Split(',').Contains(p.AccountID.ToString())` should do the trick, though I'd really recommend dealing with integers instead of strings.